# fadeIn, slideDown and other functions that require display:none not work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function loadframe(){
    $("#orderblock").fadeIn("slow");
}
```

```html
<div id="orderblock">
    <div>
        <object id="widget" data="....somecontent...."  onload="loadframe()"></object>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#widget {
    width: 630px;
    height: 480px;
}
#orderblock {
    left: 125px;
    margin: auto;
    display: none;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 518px;
    background: url("./img/bgOrder.png") no-repeat;
    width: 648px;
}
```

`fadeIn` does not work, but `fadeOut` works well (with `display: block` of course). `slideDown` has the same trouble, and `slideUp` also works well.

**UPD:**
after changing the "object" to "iframe" all works because `object` is obsolete and doesn't support the `onload` event handler that I had set up for it, so my jQuery code was never getting called.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Can you be more specific?

Comment: The `left:1125px;` instruction in your CSS will do nothing since the `#orderblock` element is in the normal flow of the document. Use `position:xyz` to have that work.

Answer (score 0):

They all seem to work for me:

```js
loadframe();

function loadframe(){
   $("#orderblock").fadeIn("slow");
   $("#orderblock").slideUp("slow");
   $("#orderblock").slideDown("slow");
   $("#orderblock").fadeOut("slow");
}
```

```css
#widget {
 width: 50px; 
 height: 50px;
}

#orderblock {
  display:none;
  background: url("./img/bgOrder.png") no-repeat;
  background:yellow;
  margin: auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="orderblock">
    <div>
       <object id="widget" data="....somecontent...."  onload="loadframe()"></object>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: take widget url  "http://widget.evos.in.ua/?dispatchingID=284"
and try again without manual calling of "loadframe();"

Answer (score 0):

After changing the "object" to "iframe" all works.

Comment: Because `object` is obsolete and doesn't support the `onload` event handler that you had set up for it. Your question had nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: My guide contains wrong information. Sorry for your time.